# SQL Server 2008 R2 Install stuck

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-installer

When I try to install my SQL Server 2008 R2, it keeps getting stuck at **SqlEngineDBStartConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu64**

I found in other issues that I should kill the `msiexec` process but I can't find it.

[image]

What should I do? Thank you

Comment: be informed that SQL Server 2008 R2 lifetime ends in July 20, 2019

Comment: Did you install the .NET framework? I vaguely remember this was a prerequisite, but the installer did not mention this. I recon V3.5

Comment: @MarcBrekoo Yes I made sure that it was installed when the issue first occurred. now I have 4 instances of SQLexpress that I cannot fully install or uninstall.

Comment: Have you tried installing a supported version of SQL Server? If it's express, why 2008R2?

Comment: @Larnu I can only use 2008r2 for my app :/

Comment: Perhaps it's timr to talk to your vendor and upgrade too then?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [SQL 2008 Fails to Install](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6491c614-56ee-4c31-ba12-8a766ef806d5/sql-2008-fails-to-install-on-windows-7-sqlenginedbstartconfigactioninstallconfigrccpu64-never?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade#00eee3ff-7620-4553-8657-b6d66fec20ba)

Answer (score 7):

Wasted couple of days on this, that is untill I found this [thread](http://buildsoftsupport.com/knowledge-base/sql-installation-error-could-not-find-the-database-engine-startup-handle/):

This simple solution worked for me.

Simply change the account name to Authority/System.

 This should work for 2008 as well.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This also worked for SQL Server 2019! You saved my life

Comment: not working :(  in express R2

Comment: It worked for me, whereas no other solution I've found on internet worked. Thanks!
I'm using Windows 11 and SQL Server 2022.