# SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup Stuck in Installation Progress in Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2, but it stuck in `Installation Progress`, like in the below picture

[image]

So If any one have an Idea about this case?

As I follow this [SQL Server 2008 R2 Install stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363429/sql-server-2008-r2-install-stuck)

But I didn't find any solution......

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - why are you installing such an old, no longer supported version of SQL Server? You should really be using a more recent version by now

Comment: I've seen this problem and killed the problem install task via task manager that was using 100% CPU. The installation then completed.